# Trying to inject the session into request body within asynchronous function in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am trying to inject a session value into the request so i can use it on different situation on my app. What i am doing is calling a function by giving the id to search for a user into database and return me the name of that specific user. The issue i am facing is when i try to declare the session, it looks like is not working or the callback is not letting this new value out.

Let me show you my code example for an better idea:

```
The middleware

var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var router = express.Router();
var userSession = require('../../helpers/user/userSession');

router.use(function(req, res, next){
  if (req.method == "GET") {
    if (!req.user) {
        req.session.username = '';
    }else{

        var sess = userSession.findUser(req.user, function(err, user){
            if (user) {
                console.log(user); //It contains the value i need
                req.session.username = user; // Supposed to inject the user value to the username session variable.
            };
          console.log(req.session.username); //it works until here, out of this function not anymore.
        });
console.log(req.session.username); //the req.session.username is empty now
    };
    return next();
}else{
    return next();
}
});
```

Check if user exist

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');   
var User = mongoose.model('database')

module.exports = {

findUser: function(user, callback){

    User.findOne({ 'unq_id' : user }, function(err, user){
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' +err);
            return callback(err, false);
        };
        if (user) {
            //console.log(user);
            return callback(null, user.user_collection.firstname);
        }else{
            return callback(err, false);
        };
    });
}
}
```

One idea is to give to that sess variable the value of user, but it appears very difficult since is asynchronous call. I am sure some of might have run into this issue.
How can i get around this? any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: You also don't want to return the callback - just call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (req.method == "GET") {
        if (!req.user) {
            req.session.username = '';
            next();
        } else {
            userSession.findUser(req.user, function(err, user){
                if (user) {
                    req.session.username = user;
                };
                next();
            });
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

That way it won't go to the next middleware until after the username has been retrieved.

Comment: Yes that did the trick, You saved my day buddy. Thank you. :)